# How to pass argument in @selector in UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, selector

I have this in my table header view section:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
```

I want to pass the section number in the method `sectionHeaderTapped` so i can recognize which section got tapped.

My method implementation looks like this:

```
-(void)sectionHeaderTapped:(NSInteger)sectionValue {
    NSLog(@"the section header is tapped ");    
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method `sectionHeaderTapped` should have one of the following signatures:

```
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped;
```

You have to figure out the cell that was tapped using the coordinates of the tap.

```
-(void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
    UITableViewCell* tappedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tapIndexPath];
}
```

You can probably get the section header using that method. But it may be easier to attach a different gesture recognizer to each section header.

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // ...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    return headerView;
}
```

And then

```
-(void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *headerView = gestureRecognizer.view;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yea i have used different gestures for each section , not the best way but way easier ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternate : You can add `UIButton` on the `tableHeaderView` and get click of button.